# Nodejs not sending response to Angular?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have a doozy that I can't figure out whats going on.

1. In Mongo, I do a document.find(), which returns an array of object/s - All good.
2. I'm then trying to send on two objects back to the Angular Controller, the document object/s and the length of the array of objects.

Code:

```
function loadConnections(req, res) {
getConnections(req.user)
.then(function(results){
    console.log('here');
    console.log(results);
    console.log(results.length);

    var returnObject = {}
    returnObject.count = results.length;
    //returnObject.results = results[0]; // PROBLEM LINE
    res.status(200).send(returnObject);
});
}
```

Problem I'm facing.  In this scenario, it returns an array with 1 object.  The array looks like:

```
[{id: XXX, test: YYY, test1: ZZZ}]
```

These have been what I've tried and tested:

```
returnObject.results = results[0].id; // works
returnObject.results = results[0].test; // works
returnObject.results = results[0].test1; //works
returnObject.results = results[0]; // doesn't work
returnObject.results = results; //doesn't work
```

But if I try to pass the entire object or the entire array, it hits an issue and doesn't send the response to the controller.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what do you mean with "doesn't work"? what's the value of returnObject.results when you are assigning results[0]?

Comment: Logs the object: {id: XXX, test: YYY, test1: ZZZ}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was my lodash library.  I was using _.pluck and somewhere along the way, it's stopped working.  Had to update it to _.map.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express, try to do a

```
res.send(200, returnObject);
```

or

```
res.json(200, returnObject);
```

that should do the trick!

Comment: Gave that a shot, but didn't work, plus got the warning that it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would just calculate the length of the array after it arrives in my Angular client, rather than on the server. However, you should be able to accomplish what you're trying to do by doing this:

```
var returnObject = {
    'count': results.length,
    'results': results
};
res.json(returnObject);
```

Here's the doc:  http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json

Also just for general troubleshooting, the first thing you want to do is figure out where the inconsistency is starting. Does the data look right on the server before you send the response? Does the data look right on the client when your API handler receives the response? (I'm assuming $resource, or maybe you're using $http). So add a line like this just before you send the response from the server, and then add a similar line just after you receive the response in the client:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(returnObject, null, 2));
```

Comment: OK...so added two logs before sending as you suggested.  One just logging the returnObject, the other logging with stringify.  The stringify log doesn't log anything.  What does that mean?

Comment: That seems really odd. Are you sure there wasn't a typo or something? You don't **need** to stringify it, that just makes it easier to read. The main point was to do a log just before sending and a log just after receiving (on the client).

Comment: 100% positive.  No spelling mistakes.  I've even tried changing the object values to hardcoded text and then outputting it.  It just seems that it doesn't like sending the whole object.

Comment: I'm stumped then. The next thing I would try is to just res.json(results) and see what you get in the client.

Comment: Yeah thats the issue, the client doesn't get the response.  So for some reason, its not liking sending the results, and therefore its not actually sending anything, so client is left hanging.